# right use of this - cannot read property emit of undefined in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have in an angular component this piece of code:

```
  @Output() fixPercentChanged = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

And I have this event:

```
fixChanged(e) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let fix = e.component.option('value');
      this.fixPercentChanged.emit(100 - fix);
    }, 100); 
  }
```

This event is binded in the markup to a keydown event of an input element:

```html
<dxi-item dataField="fix" [label]="{text: 'Fix %'}" editorType="dxNumberBox"
                [editorOptions]="{format: '#,##0.00\'%\'', onKeyDown: fixChanged, valueChangeEvent: 'keyup'}">
        <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="A mező kitöltése kötelező"></dxi-validation-rule>
      </dxi-item>
```

It gets fired, but the console says, that `fixPercentChanged` is undefined. If I print `this` to the console, I get the `dx-number-box` input element. `this` should refer in this case to the component itself. How to rewrite the function in oder to correct this?

Comment: You don't show how `fixChanged` is bound, give a [mre], but almost certainly https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/3001761.

Comment: I have edited the question. I bind the fixChanged event the standard way.

Comment: You're passing an object to `editorOptions`, presumably that's what's breaking the binding.

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe, your link pointed out the issue. This is the right syntax:

```
  fixChanged = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let fix = e.component.option('value');
      this.fixPercentChanged.emit(100 - fix);
    }, 100); 
  }
```

Now, `this` refers to the component itself and the event gets emitted.